# how do I LoadModel() from a stream using the Autodesk.PDF extension

Tags: autodesk-forge

Love the Autodesk.PDF extension. If I have resources in blob storage, how can I use the LoadModel() function with a stream?

Comment: Could you provide more details on how exactly you would *stream* the content from your blob storage to the client? As far as I know the `Autodesk.PDF` extension (and its PDF loader's `loadModel` method) just expects a URL which can either start with `urn:` (if your PDF is sitting in Forge) or with `http://` or `https://` (if you are serving the PDFs yourself).

Comment: something along these lines. we store the pdf's in azure blob storage. and would load them into memory as base64 string. Like this, for instance...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369945/converting-image-from-azure-blob-storage-to-base64

Comment: Also, if I understand you correctly, we would achieve the same thing if we stored the files in forge containers (without converting them) and use the urn: references. The viewer is able to access the files, because of the provided access token?
I know this is a slightly different question: is there a difference between loading native pdf's or "forge views converted from pdf's"?
cheers and thanks a lot for your help. Gregor

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand now. Let me respond in an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is: can the `Autodesk.PDF` extension load documents from a local, base64-encoded string, or from any custom stream? Then unfortunately no, that is not possible.

Any model you want to load into Forge Viewer, whether it's PDF or SVF (the 3D format generated by the Model Derivative service), must always be accessible via a standard URL. You should be able to generate such a URL for content in your Azure Blob Storage (for example, as explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_url).

Comment: to add to this:
I succeeded in loading "un-translated" pdf's straight from a forge bucket. 
The scope required to load the file is Scope.DataRead and 
the file path can be obtained from the buckets/:bucketKey/objects api using the Scope.BucketRead scope and is in the form: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/fancyname.forge.x1.persistent/objects/fancy_file_name.pdf

I did not succeed in loading a pdf from azure blob storage. There is a fair bit of cors config required on azure, and the forge viewer attaches it's own token. I would love to see a working example for this...